# Laravel how to insert random password automatically

Tags: php, laravel

With Laravel 5.4, I have users table

```
Users table:
- id
- email
- password
- created_at
- updated_at
```

then when I insert new user data, I want to generate random password (like 9c41Mr2) automatically.

For example, once I insert one data:

```
$data = [
    'email' => 'test@example.com',
];

DB::table('users')->insert($data);
```

I want new row in MySQL like this:

```
id: 1 (generated by autoincrement)
email: test@example.com
password: 9c41Mr2 (wow! automatic!)
created_at: 2017-06-14 01:00:00
updated_at: 2017-06-14 01:00:00
```

so, could anyone tell me the best way in Laravel? Thanks.

PS: don't worry about password hashing, I made my question simple.

Comment: With Laravel 10 you are able to generate secure, random passwords via `$pwd = Str::password();` (`use Illuminate\Support\Str;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mutator method to set the password. Override the method by adding:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = 'some random password generator';
}
```

see the documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

You don't need to use the $value parameter at all when setting the attribute.

Comment: Is it possible to mutate password attribute without writing code `$user->password = 'something';` ? Will mutator work in my case?

Comment: Yep, as @Mathieu posted below, you can use the bcrypt helper to generate the random password when the User model is saved for the first time. Then later on you can update/change the password as needed.

Comment: OH Great!! so simple. thanks both. i will try mutator. thanks.

Comment: This wasn't what @Namika.L was asking. It was about if it was possible to execute the mutator without calling `$user->password = '';` which nobody seems to have addressed and so none of the answers are valid in the context of the question because calling `DB::table('users')->insert($data);` will not call the mutator

Answer (score 12):

@Mathieu answer needs amending in light of some new changes to Laravel. Now generate the password using the following facades:

```
Hash::make(Str::random(10))
```

eg.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public function setpasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make(Str::random(10));
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In your User model :

```
public function setpasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make(Str::random(10));
}
```

Comment: Raises undefined-function warning, see the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61594061/8740349

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers require that the password mutator be called explicitly (by either passing an empty password in the model attributes or by calling `$user->password = '';`

This would fail to insert if `password` wasn't in the attributes list, this is the needed code for it to be generated if `password` isn't filled

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class User extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        //...
        'password',
    ];
    
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function save( array $options = [] ) {
        if ( ! $this->exists && empty( $this->getAttribute( 'password' ) ) ) {
            $this->password = Str::random( 16 );
        }
        return parent::save( $options );
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute( $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make( $value );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple case, just use a [`Mutator`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) for your password, but, if your application grows up, it's considered to use [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers)